# Change XTERM change background color without clearing the screen?

Tags: colors, xterm

Is there a way to change the background color an an `xterm` window without clearing the screen? I want to have a prompt that changes the entire screen's color, but I don't want to clear the screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance like this: `echo -e '\e]11;rgb:cc/ff/cc\a'` (yields a light green background).

For more possibilities, check the [xterm control sequences documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.pdf).

Comment: Do you mean `\033` for `\e`?

Comment: yes. `\e` is escape (`^[`, `\033`), `\a` is bell (`^G`, `\007`)

Comment: So why do you want a bell?

Comment: According to the document I cited, the control sequence is `<escape>]11;` + color name + `<bell>`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. Unfortunately that sequence doesn't work on my Apple Terminal client, which is supposed to implement xterm sequences but I guess doesn't.

Comment: Well, it works nicely with xterm, but it does not even work with GNOME Terminal. How disappointing. Thanks again.

Comment: Gnome-terminal supports these too. Probably you were using an older version.

Comment: To change the foreground color, change the `\e11` to `\e10`. This worked great on my MacOS Terminal.app. These are VT100 escape sequences... probably older than your parents, so they should work.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Uwe's answer,
The code to change the the background is: `'\e]11;#_<color_number>_\a'`

`echo -e "\e]11;#ff0000\a"` changes the background to red
`echo -e "\e]11;#006600\a"` changes the background to green (00ff00 is to bright for me)
`echo -e "\e]11;#0000ff\a"` changes the background to blue
`echo -e "\e]11;#000000\a"` changes the background to black

`\e` can be replaced with `\033`,
`\a` can be replaced with `\007`

For completeness, the code to change the the foreground is: `'\e]10;#_<color_number>_\a'`
`echo -e "\e]10;#000000\a"` changes the foreground to black
`echo -e "\e]10;#ffffff\a"` changes the foreground to white

(Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232881/urxvt-change-background-color-on-the-fly/242139#242139)